# find video codec from terminal

Tags: terminal, script, command-line, h.264

I'm writing some shell scripts that automatically convert some video files. Except I don't want to run the conversion on files that are already h264 encoded. Is there a way I can tell via a terminal command whether a video has a certain codec?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work for `.avi` files (at least it didn't for one I tried), but for `.mp4` or `.mov` files, it should.

To list a file's codecs:

```
$ mdls -name kMDItemCodecs "/path/to/some/file.mp4"
kMDItemCodecs = (
    "H.264",
    AAC
)
```

To find files that are movies, but don't have the H.264 codec:

```
mdfind "kMDItemContentTypeTree == 'public.movie' && kMDItemCodecs != '*H.264*'"
```

Comment: Isn't that because Quicktime components don't ship any of the various AVI codecs? I imagine `mdls` is almost exclusively functional to the MPEG series of codecs and not much more.

Comment: FWIW, QuickTime Player's Movie Inspector *does* list the AVI file's codecs.

Comment: Good point :). That also goes in line with your public.movie != H.264 in your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

With ffmpeg : ffmpeg -i video_file

see : http://videotranscoding.wikispaces.com/GetVideoMetadata

Comment: The provided link is broken.